# I want to control the width of text in pdf file to not overflow how?

Tags: flutter, text, width

```
pw.Text(descDiv, textAlign: pw.TextAlign.left,  style:const pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 10)),
```

but with text overflow don't works

```
pw.Text(descDiv, textAlign: pw.TextAlign.left,  style:const pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 10), overflow: pw.TextOverflow.ellipsis,),
```

someone help me??

Answer (score 1):

You can try this function

```
String handleOverflow(String text, double maxWidth) {
  const ellipsis = '...';

  if (text.length <= 3 || maxWidth <= 0) {
    return text;
  }

  final ellipsisWidth = ellipsis.characters.length * 5; 

  while (text.length > 1 && text.length * 5 > maxWidth - ellipsisWidth) {
    text = text.substring(0, text.length - 1);
  }

  return text + ellipsis;
}
```

And use it like this

```
pw.Text(
    handleOverflow(descDiv, 200), 
    textAlign: pw.TextAlign.left,
    style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
  )
```

Comment: it's already inside a container with width, but no accept .ellipsis, like the function not exists!

Comment: [link](https://www.portalcri.com.br/st10sports/meu-admin/print.jpg)

Comment: Sorry the pw.Text class in the pdf package doesn't have a direct overflow property like in Flutter's regular Text widget. 
I edited my answer; just try to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

my solution...

```
String _myElipiss(String valor) {
    //limited 18 max chars
    String retorno = "";
    if (valor.toString().length<=18) {
      retorno = valor;
    }else {
      retorno = '${valor.toString().substring(0,18)}...';
    }
    return retorno;
  }
```